# Can I wrap a complete class using a decorator in python?

Tags: python, wrapper

I have a complex function with many parameters. I have the idea to use a class, module, funcion, etc, where I define the parameters, and procedures that I will pass to the big function.

I wrote this code that actually works. But I dont know if it is "legal" to do so.

```
from functools import wraps

def myfunc (value) :
    print 'myfunc' , value

def somewrapper  (f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_class () :
        print "inside wrapper"
        print hasattr(f,'foomember')
        return myfunc ('wrapped')
    return decorated_class

@somewrapper
class mymodelclass :
    some = 'value'
    def foomember () :
        return 'inside class'

mymodelclass()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, class decorators are supported and perfectly valid to use in Python. The ability was introduced in Python 2.6, via [PEP 3129](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/). So, the following two pieces of code are identical:

```
class A:
  pass
A = foo(bar(A))


@foo
@bar
class A:
  pass
```

The code sample you provided doesn't really make much sense to me, since you've replaced the `mymodelclass` with a function object that doesn't return anything when you execute it, but it looks like that's just a toy example you're using to demonstrate the idea.